# PhantomJS and Crontab

Tags: python, cron, phantomjs

The following code works nicely, when I run it from the Terminal. However, when I schedule it with Crontab it only gets as far as the first print statement.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print('hello')

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
search_url = "https://www.zurich-airport.com/passengers-and-
visitors/arrivals-and-departures/arrivals"
driver.set_window_size(1124, 2000)
driver.get(search_url)
html = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

print(html)
```

This is my line in crontab: source /Users/user/.virtualenvs/master/bin/activate && python /Users/user/pyhon_code.py > "hello.txt".

I've tried adding this line as first element of the crontab:

```
PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs.
```

And also preceding the crontab with this:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Nothing works. Has anybody got a suggestion, how I could proceed?

Comment: Any errors in `hello.txt` ?

Comment: No errors, just the "hello" print out.

Comment: Oh, I know where your errors are going, they're going to stderr. Try adding `source /Users/user/.virtualenvs/master/bin/activate && python /Users/user/pyhon_code.py > "hello.txt" 2> "errors.txt"`

Comment: Now I see an "error.txt". I get the following: `/bin/sh: /Users/user/python_test.py: Permission denied`